# startMonitoring doesn't work with "WhenInUseAuthorization" permission

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I was working to a project but the monitoring function of a region didn't work.

So I created a quite simple project for testing this function.
I found a fun situation.

The code is the following below:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    let clMan = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        map.showsUserLocation = true

        clMan.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        clMan.delegate = self
        clMan.startUpdatingLocation()
        clMan.startMonitoring(for:CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude:  51.5100888, longitude: -0.134575500000008), radius: 1000, identifier: "Picca")
)

    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print(region)
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that if I change

`requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` with 
`requestAlwaysAuthorization()` my code works!.

I set Piccadilly Circus for testing with the simulation of the location.
Before going to London, I set another city and later London!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620562-requestwheninuseauthorization):

> If the user grants “when-in-use” authorization to your app, your app can start most (but not all) location services while it is in the foreground. (Apps cannot use any services that automatically relaunch the app, such as region monitoring or the significant location change service.

More from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager):

> In iOS, registered regions persist between launches of your app. If a region boundary crossing occurs while your iOS app is not running, the system automatically wakes it up (or relaunches it) in the background so that it can process the event.

Comment: But region monitoring doesn't relaunch the app! But anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Maybe you can file a radar to let you monitor regions when the app is in the foreground. I'm not sure how useful that would be though.